# Facebook JS SDK - получить всех юзеров текущего приложения?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-api

Как получить всех юзеров которые открыли и дали доступ на приложение в фейсбуке? 
Использую JS SDK version 2.7

Comment: Быть может это поможет: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066196/facebook-get-list-of-users-that-has-granted-permission-to-use-the-app

Comment: Ошибку выдает - "An access token is required to request this resource."

Comment: Очевидно что просят токен доступа.